# Setting password for MySQL root user in CLoudSQL with private IP address

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-cloud-sql

How to change the password for MySQL root user in GCP CloudSQL DB instance with private IP address . I am able to change the password using the below command from Cloud Shell with Public IP

```
    gcloud sql users set-password root  --instance=testdb --prompt-for-password
```

but it does not work for instances with Private IP address .

I can use the GCP Console to change the password but the root user is not listed under Users TAB

```
Console--> CloudSQL--> DB Instance --> Users
```

Other option seems installing gcloud on a VM in the same network as CloudSQL and change it using below command

```
gcloud sql users set-password root  --instance=testdb --prompt-for-password
```

Any other suggestion to change password for root user in a MySQL private DB instance . I need to change the password as initially the DB was created skipping the password.

Also is it more secure to use `--host=%` option while changing the password with gcloud command.

```
gcloud sql users set-password root --host=% --instance=testdb  --prompt-for-password
```

Answer (score 3):

I tested the command and I was not able to update the password not even in a Cloud SQL instance with public IP (and I did a lot of tests for example running the command from a VM). I raised a [Public Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/169886541) mentioning this issue. I recommend you add a +1 in order that the engineering team this issue into consideration and this one be resolved :)

Comment: It works for me from CLoud Shell with Public IP instances.